# Questions on Bayesian analysis of an opinion poll (an example in a book)

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

I'm sorry in advance for rather long questions. This is an example in "Bayesian logical data analysis for physical sciences" by P. C. Gregory and I have some questions about the example.

> In a poll of 800 decided voters, 440 voters supported the political party A. Let's denote the poll result as $D$. The quantity of interest is the probability that the party A will achieve a majority of at least 51% in the upcoming election, assuming the poll will be representative of the population at the time of the election.

The book regards the problem as a model selection problem. 
$M_1$ : The party A will achieve a majority with a parameter $H$ that has uniform prior in the range $0.51 \le H \le 1$. 
$M_2$ : The party A will not achieve a majority with a parameter $H$ that has uniform prior in the range $0 \le H < 0.51$.

If we have no prior reason to prefer $M_1$ over $M_2$, we can write the odds ratio $$\begin{aligned}
O_{12}&=p(M_1|D,I)/p(M_2|D,I)\\
&=p(D|M_1,I)/p(D|M_2,I)\\
&=\frac{\int_{0.51}^1 p(H|M_1,I)p(D|H,M_1,I) dH }{\int_{0}^{0.51} p(H|M_2,I)p(D|H,M_2,I) dH}\\
&=\frac{\int_{0.51}^1 (1/0.49)p(D|H,M_1,I) dH }{\int_{0}^{0.51} (1/0.51)p(D|H,M_2,I) dH}\\
&=87.68
\end{aligned}$$

Here are my questions. The book don't give explicit expressions for $p(D|H,M_1,I)$ and $p(D|H,M_2,I)$. If I use binomial distribution $$p(D|H,M_1,I)=p(D|H,M_2,I)=\frac{800! H^{440}(1-H)^{800-440}}{440!(800-440)!}$$
I get $87.03$ as a result. It is not same to the value $87.68$ of the Book. What probability distribution should I use for the likelihoods?

I have another question. Why do I have to introduce the models $M_1$ and $M_2$? Is

$$
O_{12}=\frac{\int_{0.51}^1 p(H|D,I) dH}{\int_{0}^{0.51} p(H|D,I) dH}
$$ not an appropriate aproach for the problem? It does not have the factor $(1/0.49)/(1/0.51)$ introduced with the models $M_1$ and $M_2$.

Answer (score 0):

$87.03$ looks reasonable to me as the ratio of the integrals.

The reason for the models and the $p(H|M,I)$ terms is to avoid rewarding uncertain hypotheses for their uncertainty.  You may disagree, arguing that uncertain hypotheses are more likely to be true.

For example, if one hypothesis was that $H=0.55$ exactly and the other was $0 \le H \lt 0.1$, then your final suggestion would always give $O_{12}=0$ no matter what data was supplied, since the numerator would always be an integration over a zero-length interval, while the denominator would always be positive.

The [Bayes factor example on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor#Example) may help illustrate this.  The question your book is trying to answer seems to be quantifying the extent to which the observations support the hypothesis over its alternative.